# How to SUM DISTINCT Values in a column based on a unique count in another column of a Power BI table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

| Employee | Claim Amount |
| --- | --- |
| James | 50 |
| James | 20 |
| James | 10 |
| Alex | 30 |
| Alex | 20 |

I have a table above which I would like to calculate the sum of the claim amount divide by the unique count of employee which is 2 to achieve 65 in PowerBI.

Appreciate if help could be provided with the DAX formula, thank you!

Comment: 50 + 20 + 10 = 80 / 3 = 26.6 so this is not clear.

Comment: It should divide by the number of employees in this case is 2. Gotten the help below so thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[Claim Amount]),  DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Employee]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response!! Working great!